# Is there something like "Windows Subsystem for Linux" for android?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-core, snap

Is there something like "Windows Subsystem for Linux" for android oficially supported?
I am mainly interested in apt-get or snap for commandline applications.

Comment: MultiROM Ubuntu Touch (beta for some devices) or Linux Deploy. Both require root and busybox. Termux also provides a debian-like shell environment without root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as Windows subsystem for Linux for Android. If your primary concern is using apt-get or snap on Android, then you may try Ubuntu touch based phones who use Ubuntu OS and snap.

I also found this app that says it can install Linux distro on Androids. Check here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en

Related question on Android SE 
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59863/a-real-terminal-root-or-no-root